# How to change the current path to a directory that has an space on it's name?

Tags: command-line

Well I know how to open a folder in the terminal (using cd). But when the name of this folder have space? Ex: Eclipse Indigo. If you use cd Eclipse Indigo does not recognize

Answer (score 5):

You have to escape spaces in shell

So type `cd Eclipse\ Indigo`.

Also you can use quotes as well.

```
cd "Eclipse Indigo"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can type `cd Eclipse` and then hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. Linux shell will autocomplete for you.

You can always type just some chars and then hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>, for every filename, folder name... whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Once you go into the directory of the folder, you can type `Eclipse` then press the *Tab* key on your keyboard.

```
cd Eclipse
```

Then press *Tab*