# Changing a directory with quotes and spaces.[Linux]

Tags: command-line, directory, cd-command

I've been trying to change into this directory all day with no such luck.

```
.\ \ \ \ ug1y\ \ \ ..\ \ \ \ ''\ \ "\ \ \
```

The backslashes are just blanks because I used the `ls -ab` command.

If someone could please get me into this directory I'd be forever thankful.

[image]

Comment: Error you get? Actual folder name? This question is hard to answer without knowing that.

Comment: If there aren't any single quotes in it, then just wrap the whole thing in single quotes. Does tab completion not work btw?

Comment: When trying to go change the directory it then gives me another line with the > sign to put input.

Comment: No tab won't work either. I've tried and seeing it has single and double quotes in it. i'm lost I think i need to use backslash but i'm honestly not sure.

Comment: when i copied and pasted it from the terminal it didn't show but the first " are two single quotes the second quote is a single double quote.

Comment: You use the \ to escape, not `/` so `file\ with\ spaces` . Post the name of the directory.

Comment: took a screenshot http://imgur.com/NeHXsX3 those are all the directories but once i get into one I can get into all.

Comment: pls make a "ls -al" and send a screenshot. Than do a "ls -al | hexdump -C" and also do a screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the current path to a directory that has an space on it's name?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67238/how-to-change-the-current-path-to-a-directory-that-has-an-space-on-its-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your directory name in single or double quote like this:

```
mkdir 'a    b    . "   v'
cd 'a    b    . "   v'
```

if you don't want to type all the name, you can type few characters in the beginning of directory name and press <kbd>tab</kbd> which will add the rest of directory name.

If still you cannot manage to go into this directory, share the result of `ls -la` here. So we might be able to help better

Answer (score 0):

type it out as:

```
cd ".     ug1y    ..    ''   \"   "/
```

you only need to place a \ in front of the double quote in the directory name. This will exclude that double quote from being read as a special character by BASH. And it will be read as part of the directory name.